# Does a TXV completely close when there's no thermal load whatsoever?

Tags: heat-transfer, hvac

How is a TXV supposed to behave in a no evaporator thermal load situation (for example, evaporator fan completely off)? Would it completely close, not letting any liquid refrigerant get through (and reach the pump still in the liquid phase), would it still let some liquid refrigerant leak past into the evaporator coil, eventually overcome by the pressure building up in the high pressure line, but not enough to manage to reach the evaporator's outlet without having turned into superheated vapor, or would it behave differently? Would the evaporator coil still be able to develop frost in that situation (and potentially end up making the evaporator completely unable to turn the liquid into superheated vapor)?

Thanks